# Spring Boot Devtools how to reload Maven multiple dependent modules in the independent module?

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot, spring-boot-devtools

I have a multiple modules Maven with this structure:

```
app-parent
  -------app-library (Hibernate data entities layer)
  -------app-main (contains app-library as dependency), Spring Boot web application.
```

The simple pom.xml files for these folders:

- app-parent/pom.xml

> ```
> <modules>
>    <module>app-library</module>
>    <module>app-main</module>
> </modules>
> <packaging>pom</packaging>
> <name>app-parent</name>
> ```

- app-library/pom.xml

> ```
> <parent>
>     <groupId>test</groupId>
>     <artifactId>app-parent</artifactId>
>     <version>1.0.0</version>
> </parent>
> <dependencies>
>    .... Some libraries here ....
> </dependencies>
> ```

- app-main/pom.xml

> ```
> <parent>
>     <groupId>test</groupId>
>     <artifactId>app-parent</artifactId>
>     <version>1.0.0</version>
> </parent>
> <dependencies>
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
>         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
>     </dependency>
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
>         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
>     </dependency>
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
>         <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>            
>     </dependency>
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
>         <artifactId>petascope-core</artifactId>
>         <version>${project.version}</version>
>     </dependency>
> </dependencies>
> ```

With NetBeans 8.2 and Spring Boot version 1.5.2, I used Spring Devtools to auto reload changed Java classes file (~few seconds) instead of cold restart (> 10 seconds).

On app-main folder, I run this command to set up the WebApplication which allows NetBeans to attach a debugger to port 5005:

```
mvn spring-boot:run -Drun.jvmArguments="-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=5005"
```

Also, in application.properties of app-main/src/main/resources, I added this watch to allow Spring Devtools detect the change from app-library

```
spring.devtools.restart.additional-paths=../app-library
```

So, whenever I change one java file in app-main or app-library, I can see from the terminal that Spring DevTool does the reload in few seconds.

```
     .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.5.2.RELEASE)

  INFO [08:57:20] ApplicationMain@48: Starting ApplicationMain on localhost.localdomain with PID 19645 (/home/rasdaman/rasdaman_community/build/applications/petascope/target/petascope_main/classes started by rasdaman in /home/rasdaman/rasdaman_community/rasdaman/applications/petascope/petascope_main)
 DEBUG [08:57:20] ApplicationMain@51: Running with Spring Boot v1.5.2.RELEASE, Spring v4.3.7.RELEASE
  INFO [08:57:20] ApplicationMain@637: No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
[2018-05-01 08:57:22.341] - 19645 INFO [restartedMain] --- org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService: Starting service Tomcat
[2018-05-01 08:57:22.341] - 19645 INFO [restartedMain] --- org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.11
[2018-05-01 08:57:22.361] - 19645 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] --- org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/rasdaman]: Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
  INFO [08:57:24] ApplicationMain@57: Started ApplicationMain in 3.612 seconds (JVM running for 84.418)
```

The problem is with some basic change in a method of app-library, Spring DevTools can detect the file has been saved and reload, but from the app-main where called this method, the output is still the same, e.g:

```
app-library
public class Service {
     public String returnValue() {
          // return "Value before Spring DevTools reload.";

          // !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
          // After app-main was set up from Maven command lines, I changed this line here and saved it to notice Spring DevTool to reload in the console.
          return "Value after Spring DevTools reload."
     }
}

app-main
public class TestService {

    public TestService() {
         Service service = new Service();
         // !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
         // It can only print "Value before Spring DevTools reload."
         // even though the Service file has been changed to return different value and Spring DevTools reloaded.
         System.out.println(service.returnValue());
    }
}
```

**With this problem**, I cannot just change in app-library and expect the changes will be applied in app-main. Instead, I have to stop the Maven command line, then in NetBeans click on app-main and select **Build with dependencies**, then runs Maven command line again to set up this Web Application with cold start (total: ~1 minute).

What can I do to make Spring DevTools can apply the changes from app-library to app-main instantly after I saved files in app-library? That would help to reduce the waiting time from NetBeans "Build with Dependencies".

Comment: As far as I know the spring boot dev tools are can only handle the situation if you have a single module...but as far as I know you can configure which directories will be observed ...this should solve the problem...

Comment: @khmarbaise I added app-library to be observed but it couldn't reload change. No problem.

Comment: From which level of your project have you started your `mvn spring-boot:run..`?

Comment: @khmarbaise on app-main folder.

Comment: is there any updates on this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, in app-main it needs app-library built in local repository (~/.m2/...) and the only way to update this repository is going to app-library folder and run:

```
mvn install
```

After that, stop the running Web application from command line (<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd>) and restart it with same maven command on app-main folder:

```
mvn spring-boot:run -Drun.jvmArguments="-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=5005"
```

It still takes time to cold restart app-main, but it is acceptable.